# How to add permanently active color in paging

Tags: html, css, colors, paging

My HTML code is like this

```
<section class="archive-pages">
  <ul>
    <li><a title="Pagina 1" href="virtual-assistants-network">1</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 2" href="virtual-assistants-network-2">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 3" href="virtual-assistants-network-3">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 4" href="virtual-assistants-network-4">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 5" href="virtual-assistants-network-5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

How can I give active page color to paging item so that it shows the selected page of anchor tag with background color as blue and text as white?

Comment: You do it server-side, which we can't help you with unless you tell us what language you're using, or you do it with Javascript (not recommended). Either way, this question lacks any evidence of you're having tried to solve this yourself and thus is unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: what I Tried using in Html in Wordpress site is :                  ul li.archive-pages a {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #001455 !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }                                                                    But it did not work!

Comment: How is that in any way related to the question? If I'm interpreting it correctly, you have several pages with that code and you want to show which one you're on. That CSS doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: ok then if u know it please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the language, but whatever it is the concept is the same, if you want to apply special stylings give that menu a "active" class. Then create your style like so. If you are using some type of control that builds the paging for you then you will need to manually pull the required info to build it.

HTML

```
<section class="archive-pages">
  <ul>
    <li><a title="Pagina 1" href="virtual-assistants-network">1</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 2" href="virtual-assistants-network-2" class="active">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 3" href="virtual-assistants-network-3">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 4" href="virtual-assistants-network-4">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="Pagina 5" href="virtual-assistants-network-5">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.archive-pages a.active{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:blue
}
```